# Vue-awesome swiper, two components swipes by buttons of each other

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component, swiper.js

I use vue-awesome-swiper [from here](https://github.com/surmon-china/vue-awesome-swiper) and have a problem. Swipers have buttons(prev slide, next slide) for swiping slides inside and when I place  this two components in one page they swiping slides by buttons of each other. So if I try to swipe to next slider in first swiper the second swiper will swiper to next slide too.
Here is my component code:

```
    <template>
  <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
          <div class="col-xs-12">
            <div class='mobSwip'>
              <div class="swiper-container" id="quick-view-slider">
                <swiper :options="swiperOption">
                  <swiper-slide v-for="screen in screens" :key="screen.key"><img v-bind:src="`https://admin.springsapps.com${screen.url}`"/></swiper-slide>
                  <swiper-slide v-if="!screens"><img src="@/assets/images/quick-view-1.png"/></swiper-slide>
                </swiper>
              </div>
              <!-- <div class="swiper-pagination" slot="pagination"></div> -->
              <div class="swiper-button-next"><span class="icon-play"></span></div>
              <div class="swiper-button-prev"><span class="icon-play-flip"></span></div>
              <!-- <button @click="swipeNext">next</button> -->
            </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
</template>

<script>
import 'swiper/dist/css/swiper.css'
import { swiper, swiperSlide } from 'vue-awesome-swiper'

  export default {
    props: {
      screens: {
        type: Array,
        required: false
      }
    },
    data: function () {
      return {
        swiperOption: {
          slidesPerView: 5,
          spaceBetween: 30,
          centeredSlides: true,
          // pagination: {
          //   el: '.swiper-pagination',
          //   clickable: true
          // },
          navigation: {
            nextEl: '.swiper-button-next',
            prevEl: '.swiper-button-prev'
            // nextEl: this.$el.querySelector('.swiper-button-next'),
            // prevEl: this.$el.querySelector('.swiper-button-prev')
          }
        },
      }
    },
    components: {
      swiper,
      swiperSlide
    }
  }
</script>

<style scoped>
  .swiper-slide {
    width: 60%;
  }
  .swiper-slide:nth-child(2n) {
      width: 40%;
  }
  .swiper-slide:nth-child(3n) {
      width: 20%;
  }
</style>
```

I tried to use queryselectors, getting buttons classes by refs, tried to swiping by methods what was in official docs but it does not works. The only one way this buttons work is get them by class in data object as in my code... How I can make my buttons useful and indenpendent?

Comment: On your provided code, it doesn't seem like you are using the imported `swiper` and `swiperSlide` components, please check this official example on how it use it
https://jsfiddle.net/bL983fjt/

Comment: Thank you, this example works, but I need buttons outside the <swiper> tag

Comment: I have solve it! Make it by quering ref on swiper and use this.$refs.mobileScreensSwiper.swiper.slideNext() as method

Comment: All options and events of the original Swiper are supported. What i did was using  a 'active-index' property
When clicking on your prev or next button just trigger a method that updates your screens to the correct item and index 

this.swiper.slideTo(newIndex);

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is what fixed it for me (Nuxt.js/SSR project):

1) Having both swipers in different components (not sure if it's required or not)

2) Add id attributes to button's divs:
`<div id="button-next-relacionados" class="swiper-button-next swiper-button-white"></div>`
`<div id="button-next-relacionados" class="swiper-button-next swiper-button-white"></div>`

3) In the swiper options object, refer to the new ids instead of `swiper-button-prev` and `swiper-button-next` classes:

```js
swiperOption: {
        direction: 'horizontal',
        slidesPerView: 4,
        spaceBetween: 6,
        navigation: {
          nextEl: '#button-next-relacionados',
          prevEl: '#button-prev-relacionados'
        },
```

Answer (score 1):

I use

```
this.$refs.swiper.swiperInstance.autoplay.start()
```

Answer (score -1):

I have solved it! Make it by querying ref on swiper and use

```
this.$refs.mobileScreensSwiper.swiper.slideNext()
```

as method

Answer (score -1):

```
 pagination: {
      el: '.swiper-pagination-service',
      clickable: true,
    },
```

I meet the same issue, and I have found the solution is set pagination. el is unique

When Vue-awesome-swiper interactive with Dom, it checks the match class name,
if it same className, it can not detect correct slider

Comment: I do not see how this answers the question at the top of this page, but it should. Please [edit] according to [answer] or delete the answer. Otherwise it risks being flagged as "not an answer" and being deleted.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Please provide an explanation to your code - it is very hard to understand something when it isn't explained.

Comment: Issue:  When having multiple sliders inside a page or a component, slider "A" click pagination=> pagination on slider "B" changes the same slider "A".


Reason: Because each slider has the same class name pagination.

Solution: change class name valid set pagination className is unique as the above mention